# Loop through list to find basic summary

Tags: python

I have a list with different dates .Also have daily.pc dataset which has date as one of column .I need to subset the data with respect to data and calculate few basics statistics and store the output row-wise .For Example for first element in the list 2020-03-13 : It should subset data from beginning of the dataset to 2020-03-13 plus one day .For 2nd element 2020-03-13 to 2020-03-24 plus one day and so on .

```
Sample Raw Data:
                AAP      AAPL      ALXN  ...      MSFT     ^GSPC  Total_Returns
    2019-03-04  0.986179  1.005029  0.987877  ...  0.997601  0.996119       8.979994
    2019-03-05  0.993119  0.998180  0.990373  ...  0.995012  0.998868       8.985657
    2019-03-06  1.004196  0.994246  0.972917  ...  1.000448  0.993476       8.938454
    2019-03-07  0.975692  0.988425  0.977502  ...  0.987830  0.991874       8.911831
```

List created:

```
Top_five_DD=['2020-03-13', '2020-03-24', '2020-04-06', '2020-03-17',
               '2020-03-10']
```

Code tried :

```
for label in Top_five_DD:
      
    print(daily_pc.loc[daily_pc.index==label,:])
```

The Final output should be

```
       Start Date         End Date      Difference b/w start and end date    average 
AAP 

AAPL

ALXN
```

Any help would be highly appreciated .

Comment: It looks like the dates are used as the index in your dataframe, please try `print(daily_pc.loc[label])`?

Comment: print(daily_pc.loc[daily_pc.index==label,:]) -This only subset on the element of the list ,but I want subset based on the range of list (dates)

Comment: Could you provide a [[MCVE]]? just some code that sets up your table with four or so rows, so that it is easy to create a proof of concept for it? Plus what the output  of the small example should look like. I'd expect that you can make use of the fact that your date strings are actually built in a way that they are comparable - so sorting the rows (or are they sorted already?) and then accessing the range. Would want to verify that first though.